# Elasticsearch truncate string field in query

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

To display recent exceptions on a Grafana dashboard I am doing a query on exceptions in logfiles. Grafana doesn't seem to have an option to limit a string value in table view. Of course the stacktraces are huge.

So I came up with the idea to limit this field in the used Lucene query, but I am unaware on how to do this. I tried doing this using a painless script:

```
{
 "query": {
  "match_all": {}
 },
  "script_fields": {
    "message_short": {
     "script": {
       "lang": "painless",
       "inline": "return doc['message'].value.substring(50);"
     }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't get any error but also no additional field "message_short" which I would have expected. Do I have to enable scripting support somehow? I'm running on v6.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround implemented where I have a drilldown URL ("Render value as link" in Grafana Table) where I render a link to my Kibana instance and use the Grafana variable `$__cell` that references the document_id I get from the underlying Elasticsearch query:

```
https://mykibana.host/app/kibana#/doc/myindex-*/myindex-prod-*/logs?id=$__cell&_g=h@8b5b71a
```

Not perfect, but keeps my Dashboard readable and allows more info if needed. Even better would be to add a shorted field into the ES index, but that is not possible for me currently.